# Calculating the area individually enclosed by multiple contour lines in R (SpatialLinesDataFrame)

Tags: raster, r, area, contour

**Aim**

Calculating the area and perimeter of each individual contour line (SpatialLinesDataFrame) extracted using `raster::rasterToContour()`.

**Issue**

In spite of my web searches, I seem I cannot find a viable way of calculating the area, which should entail converting the polylines (SpatialLinesDataFrame) to polygons (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame).

**Executable example**

```
#load the 'raster' package
library(raster)

#store elevation data into the 'volc' object
volc <- raster::raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package="gdistance"))

#extract the contour(s) corresponding to 180m elevation
x <- rasterToContour(volc, level=180)

#plot the elevation data
raster::plot(volc)

#add the contours
raster::plot(x, add=TRUE)
```

[image: DTM plus contours]

**What I manage to achieve**

As you can see from the above image, there are 2 different contours corresponding to 180m elevation. Using the `SDraw` package, it is possible to get a vector storing the lenght (perimeter) of each contour:

```
perimeter <- SDraw::lineLength(x, byid=T)
perimeter
[1] 822.36439  92.63713
```

**Where I am stuck**

I have not been successful in finding a similar straightforward way of working out the area enclosed by each individual contour. I have found an answer on Stackoverflow (the last one at that link) [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406507/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-within-a-contour-in-r), but I don't know how to tailor that solution to my situation.

Comment: The problem is that contours are not guaranteed to be loops if they meet the edge of the region, which is why they are stored as lines and not polygons. Its easier to get the area of an elevation model between contour levels directly from the elevation data itself than creating contours first, if that's what you are really trying to compute.

Comment: Thank you. I do see your point. That was a reproducible example, but for my purposes I would only use what I described when the polylines actually loop. I have found a viable option, which I will soon post as an answer for future reference.